# define some commands when GDB got SIGSEGV

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging

Is it possible to define some commands when GDB got `SIGSEGV`

something like:

```
b SIGSEGV
commands
i r
x/100x $sp
end
```

Comment: Instead of `b SIGSEGV`, try [`catch signal SIGSEGV`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html#index-catch-signal).